# ionic4 @ionic/angular ionChange or ion-select not working as expected on form reset

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Current behavior:
I think this was a problem before with angular but angular fixed it with the emitEvent:false option, which is now not working in ionic.
I have a reactive form when I want to reset the form with reset even with {emitEvent: false} option it emits an event and by that it run ionChange which is not correct behaver if the option emitEvent:false.

Expected behavior:
if the option emitEvent: false, ionChange must not run.

This is what I have in my .html file

```
 <ion-select slot="end" (ionChange)="onProvinceChanged($event)" formControlName="provinceCtrl" [interfaceOptions]="customPopoverOptions" interface="popover" placeholder="{{'province' | translate}}">
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id"> {{city.name | translate}} </ion-select-option> 
 </ion-select>
```

And this is what I have in my .ts file

```
onClearFilter(){ this.form.controls['provinceCtrl'].reset('',{emitEvent: false}); }
```

my current version

```
Ionic CLI : 5.4.5 (C:\Users\AMD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.11.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.3
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.2
@angular/cli : 8.3.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.0.0
```

Comment: `ionChange` doesn't care how the values are set or reset, it is not attached to angular forms in any way, it just listens to when value changes and acts accordingly, so `emitEvent: false` doesn't work in this case, as it affects only form.

Comment: @AJT82 You are right, but the problem is that I can not use (change) on ion-select it does not support that, I must use (ionChange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I mentioned in comment, `ionChange` doesn't care how the values are set or reset, it is not attached to angular forms in any way, it just listens to when value changes and acts accordingly, so `emitEvent: false` doesn't work in this case, as it affects only form.

So, since it affects only form, remove the `ionChange` and instead listen to `valueChanges` of that formcontrol, since `valueChanges` is not fired when `emitEvent` is set to `false`:

```ts
this.form.get('provinceCtrl').valueChanges.subscribe((value: number) => {
  // do stuff!
})
```

Also remember to unsubscribe when component is destroyed!